# Clear all form field in react, using react hook forms

Tags: forms, react-forms

I am creating a login form and want to clear the form when form submitted.I am using react hook form ,here are my codes..

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const name = data.name;
    const email = data.email;
    const pass = data.password;
    const confirmPass = data.confirmPassword;
    console.log(data)

}

 <form className="mt-6" id='signupForm' onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in `React Hook Form` called `reset` on successful form submission run `reset` function. It will clear all the form values.

[Example of working.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-adapting-existing-form-forked-hfc2zh?file=/src/index.js)